# I need help to Timestamp specific tabs in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Here is the current script I have written in App Script to timestamp but i need to be able to timestamp specific tabs in a doc:

```
function TIMESTAMPOACStart(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if (col == 4) {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,5).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

What do i need to edit to get this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Look in google documentation and you can see all you need which is specifically [getsheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)().

So ultimately something like this...

```
function TIMESTAMPOACStart(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var yourSheetName = "sheet3"// <-- or whatever sheet name you want to apply to.
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(yourSheetName);

  if (col == 4) {
    mySheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function TIMESTAMPOACStart(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];//only works on these sheets
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == 4) {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 5).setValue(new Date()); 
  }
}
```